# How to check if ipcMain.handleOnce is set?

Tags: electron, event-handling

Trying to avoid “Error occurred in handler for 'operator:import': Error: Attempted to register a second handler for 'operator:cancelImport'” error.

```js
const onCancel = () => {
  done = true
}
ipcMain.handleOnce("operator:cancelImport", onCancel)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to the title of your question, but to "avoid the error" (e.g. when reloading page in dev mode): Electron doesn't complain if you remove a handler that is not set yet.

You can do:

```js
const onCancel = () => {
  done = true
}

ipcMain.removeHandler("operator:cancelImport")

ipcMain.handleOnce("operator:cancelImport", onCancel)
```